# How best to pass Values back from UI to Custom SSIS Transform

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm in the process of creating a `custom SSIS Transform`. Something along the lines of the Derived column Transform that comes with SSIS.   I have a list of the Input columns in a DataGridView:

[image]

The user will be able to supply a value to replace in the even that the value of the item is null.

In the past I have used `CustomPropertyCollection` to save single values to the `ComponentMetadata`.  My question is.  In this case where I will be storing a value for each of the input columns how should I go about that?

I have considered creating a xml string where I store the `Inputcolumn id` and the value I want to used to replace it with.   But this seams like over kill to me.  Does anyone know of a better way of going about this?

I have created, Dataflow tasks, and connection managers before. This is my first data transformation task.

Comment: Hi,as this is associated with  ComponentMetaData property of the ScriptMain class..Please add the vb.net and c# tag as well

Comment: added C# as VB wont help me much :)

Comment: lad mig tænke over svaret

Comment: I hope this would help you ,http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/

Comment: not really I need to make my own not download someone elses.

Comment: you get source code as well  from this site,       http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SsisComponents/SsisComponents.sln